# Calculating Average in Matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, average

I have a simulation in Matlab that produces a 3D matrix (date, start point, trial) of size <103x11x6 double>. It is a simulation that returns a simulated interest rate over 103 time steps for 11 different starting values. This is repeated 6 times.
 I wish to simply create a new matrix that returns the average of all these trials. i.e. a single time series for each starting point where the time series is the average interest rate of all the trials for each time point.
Many thanks for any help.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mean.html

Comment: That means `mean(TrialMatrix,3)` should give you what you need, as it takes the mean over the third dimension of the matrix and returns a 103x11 matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a 3D matrix (date, start point, trial)

If the matrix is M, then

```
A = mean(mean(M,3),2);
```

then `A` has one dimension `date` and each value of `A` is the average over the 11x6 matrix at that date.  `mean(M,3)` is a 2-d matrix, which you can then take the mean of.

Interestingly,

```
A = mean(M(:,:),2);
```

will give you the same result.  M(:,:) will collapse M down to 2 dimensions, with the first one preserved and all the later dimensions (only 2nd and 3rd in your case) collapsed to a single dimension.

Comment: Thank you. mean(M,3) gives me exactly what I need. Your extra suggestion will be useful later. Many thanks.